# What is the scope of IFS

Tags: linux, bash

I'm confused by the scope of IFS, different people seem to think that it's session based vs just within a script once it's been set/changed.

My issue is, I have a while read that has potentially blank columns, which offsets the variables I'm setting them into.  If I change the delimiter in the data from a tab, and update IFS to use that new delimiter, I'm concerned that it might affect other read commands within my work flow.

If I do something like:

```
while IFS='|' read var1 var2 var3
```

Will that only change the value of IFS for that specific while loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will that only change the value of IFS for that specific while loop?

No, actually it will change it only for the `read` part. Within the `while` loop's body, and after that, it will return to its default, because it will have only been set within the context of the `read` command.

You can write a simple loop over some file that proves this, e.g. with a CSV file with two columns:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS="," read a b; do
  echo $a $b
done < "input.csv"
echo $IFS
```

The last line of output will be appearing empty, as by default, IFS is `<space>`, `<tab>` and `<newline>`, thus `$' \t\n'`. See [the POSIX spec for details](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05).

If you have (accidentally?) set IFS to some other value for your entire script, `unset IFS` resets it to its default.

In addition, if by “session”, you mean a single script (or shell that executes a script), once that script exits, the value will not be saved. Your terminal does not preserve it over multiple sessions either, of course.

Comment: @DanielListon There is a semantic difference between it being unset and being set to the default, but Bash treats it the same: “If IFS is unset, or its value is exactly <space><tab><newline>, the default, then …” and “If the value of IFS is null, no word splitting occurs.” – see `man bash`.

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  I should have taken warning when the man pages reference the "I" in IFS as "Internal" instead of the proper "Input" field separator.  Based on the "default" I have to question the point or redundancy of the shell setting IFS in the first place. :(

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> while IFS='|' read var1 var2 var3
> ```
>
> Will that only change the value of IFS for that specific while loop?

**No. It will only change the value of IFS for that specific `read`.** In general the loop is from `while` to `done`, it may include many commands.

Neither `IFS` nor `read` are special here. Take this general code:

```
( export a=0
printenv a
while a=1 printenv a && printenv a; printenv a; true; do
   printenv a
   break
done; printenv a )
```

The result is:

> ```
> 0
> 1
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> ```

Only the second `printenv` gets the modified value!

Notes:

- I used a subshell for two reasons:

  1. you can paste the entire code before your shell executes anything;
  2. the code won't affect the `a` variable in your current shell.
- I used `printenv a`, not `echo $a` because in the latter case the shell would expand `$a` to the value seen by *the shell itself* before even `echo` started (regardless whether `echo` is a shell builtin or a separate executable). The syntax `variable=foo some_command` hardly ever changes the variable for the shell itself (the exception is `variable=foo export variable`). If you changed every `printenv a` to `echo $a` in my code, you would get all `0`-s.

Answer (score 0):

In shell scripting, IFS stands for Internal Field Separator. It is a special environment variable that determines how the shell splits words into fields or tokens. The default value of IFS is whitespace (space, tab, and newline), which means that by default, the shell splits words at these whitespace characters.

When you use the read command without specifying a delimiter, IFS is used to split the input into fields based on whitespace characters. Each field is assigned to a separate variable.

example:

```
#!/bin/bash
line="Hello,World"
IFS=',' read -r field1 field2 <<< "$line"
echo "Field 1: $field1"
echo "Field 2: $field2"
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, as per you code block, the IFS value is being set only for the loop.
Once the control comes out of the loop, IFS gains its value prior to entering the loop.
This will not impact other read operation in the same shell script.
I tried something like this:

```
echo "Changing IFS value to ','."
OLD_IFS_VALUE=$IFS
IFS='|'
CURRENT_IFS_VALUE=$IFS
echo "IFS value before entering the loop : $CURRENT_IFS_VALUE"
while IFS=',' read name age city gender
do
    echo $name $age $city $gender
done < "testdata1.csv"
echo "After loop value of IFS : $IFS"
```

So I had set IFS to '|' before the loop.
Inside the loop, I used IFS value as ','.
Once the control went out of the loop, IFS value was '|'.

Comment: -1 because the strict answer is "no". "Once the control went out of the loop" should rather be "once the control passed `read`". There are places *inside the loop* where `IFS` is not `,`. See my answer.